# How to remove substring that is in another column in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

I want to delete text part from current column. This text part is presented in another column. To be clear here is the image:

[image]

So I want to delete **Model** number from **Title** column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SUBSTITUTE function like this:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")`

This will take the text that's in A1, and replace the text that's in B1 with nothing.

[Read more about SUBSTITUTE here.](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php)

Comment: I would make the, perhaps trivial, edit of trimming the trailing space from the output:

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,""))`

Hope this helps. Cheers,